# how can I get non repeated rows on fetching data using keyword limit in big query and python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have millions of rows with log as unique id.
To process the data and save to another table
I am doing something like this

```
action = """select ID_log, ID_send_message, ID_send, ID_message, ID_recipient,email, action, action_date from `internal.actions` where ID_log > {} limit 10000""".format(Id_log_number)
actions_full = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(action, project_id='mt-int')
```

After processing the data I will save it in separate table
ID log will be the last id log of the generated table action_log. Now on running the above code multiple time I am getting the same set of row again and again. Is there a way to get the rows at a specific pattern such that I don't get same set of data. i am using time.sleep to avoid pulling data from cache.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same data back because your `WHERE` statements finds the first row to match the criteria and then you are using `LIMIT` which limits your results to first 10000 rows, no matter how many more you have. Try to remove `LIMIT 10000` and you should get different result every time you update your table.

If you would like to get last *n* rows from database then you can simply sort your results descending and then apply limit to get only desired amount of results, like:

```
action = "SELECT ID_log, ID_send_message, ID_send, ID_message, ID_recipient,email, action, action_date FROM `internal.actions` WHERE ID_log > {} ORDER BY ID_log DESC LIMIT 10000".format(Id_log_number)
```

Comment: but i cant push 1 million row at time  to process .. is there a way to get bulk data  or sample data without using limit .. . If i use the max(ID_log) instead of last id log of the first batch will it help.

Comment: Why can't you deal with 1 million rows? It shouldn't be such a big problem if your database and table are properly set up... I also updated my answer a bit although I'm not really sure anymore if I understand what your problem really is :)

Comment: I am taking the data in a data frame in python processing it and saving it in the separate table back to bigquery. As time goes data will increase and i have to process same used   .. in sort It wont be scalable thats why where claws and limits has been put. I will take a batch of 10k data process it and save it while ID_log will act as a flag. I also noted that log ids are coming randomly instead of in organised manner as it is generated.

Comment: It looks to me like there is nothing wrong with your query as such, it works as it should, but looks like you have a different problem here. Maybe to ask a different question and describe it better?

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to give you the same results, because the same query and the same conditions,
if you want to read data as chunks from google bigquery table so you don't overload the server's memory, try google pagination for bigquery ([document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#bigquery_browse_table-python))